# Is my CPU core/CPU proximity too high in temperature?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

As mentioned by the title 'is my CPU core/CPU proximity to high in temperature?'. The underneath of my macbook gets seriously hot. Not only this but if an application is being 'verified' when opened or when I open a browser such as google chrome, the fans get extremely noisy. I've had a look online but there seems to be difference of opinion. Can anyone tell me what they think with the stats below? It averages around 70s/80s.

[image: Macbook Stats]

[image: Temp Stats]

Comment: 70s - 80s is pretty warm! Have you opened your case up to check for **crud** that may have built up on the fan blades or fins on the heat sink?